# Is it possible to estimate accuracy, precision and recall with the given data?

Tags: accuracy, confusion-matrix, precision, false-positive-rate

Background: I talked to my friend today and according to herm(him/her) I can calculate precision, recall and accuracy with the current information.

Total instances *T*: 19,532.

Instances belonging to class *F*: **8829**.

What my classifier totally found, lets call it *TS*: **11,120**.

The number of instances of *TS* belonging to *F*, lets call it *FTS*: **6622**.

What is TP, TN, FP and FN here?
From my understanding I get these, not sure if it is correct though.

1. (TP: 6622)
2. (TN: 11120-6622=4498)
3. (FP:11120-8829=2291)

Comment: What does "What my classifier totally found" mean? Is it number of positives, i.e. class F, your classifier found out of 19532?

Comment: @gunes Yes, out of 19,532 instances, my classifier classified 11,120 to belong to class TS. Out of 11,120 of those instances, 6622 belonged to a the desired class F.

Comment: There should be two classes: F = positives, and F' = negatives. No class TS as I understand. So, 11,120 is classified as class F by your classifier. But, 6622 were really F. Isn't it?

Comment: @gunes Yes. 6622 is really F class, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll slightly round up the numbers for ease of notation.

1. Your TP, i.e. True Positives is correct.
2. TN (True Negatives) + FP (False Positive) = Total Negatives = $19.5K-8.8K=10.7K$. Plug-in the FP in (3) and get TN.
3. FP (False Positives) = We called Positive - True Positive = $11.1K-6.6K\approx 4.5K$ (i.e. your answer for TN is actually FP).

Precision, recall and accuracy can be calculated easily from these three.

Comment: I became very confused by this answer. Did I get this correct?
FP = **4.5K**
TP = **6.6K**
TN = **10.7k**
FN = incorrectly rejected..?

Comment: Wasn't 4.5k FP and not 11.7K -4.5K?

Comment: Cheers! How do you calculate the FN?

Comment: FN is False Negatives = (We called Negative) - (True Negatives). TN is found in (2). We called 19.5K-11.1K negatives in total.

Comment: Total negatives is either 19.5K - 11.1K or 19.5K - 8.8K = 10.7K. Did you accidently type wrong? :P 
Depending on your answer I get:
FN: 2207 = (Total negatives = 8 829) - (True negatives = 6205)
FN: 4498‬ = (Total negatives =10703 ) - (True negatives = 6205)

Comment: I need to be careful with numbers, while you need to be careful with concepts :) Let me revise "Total Negatives" is 10.7K as in my answer (not 11.7K) which is the number of Negatives in the dataset. "Number of samples we called negative" is not "Total Negative". Because, there are a total of 19.5K samples and your classifier called 11.1K of them as "positive", your classifier called 19.5K-11.1K = 8.4K as Negative, which is "(We called Negative)" in my comment.

Comment: +1. [The Wikipedia page on sensitivity and specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is long, but has a lot of very good information and examples.

Comment: @gunes Ty. I think I got it right this time. These formulas how to calculate these, do they exist on the wiki page or some other page or is it just common sense? 
Btw this is the final result:
TP:6622
FN: 2207
FP: 4498
TN: 6205

Comment: @StephanKolassa I will look into that page and try to verify my answers.

Comment: @sockevalley seems correct. It's both common sense and formulas (which is present in Stephen's link, i.e. the wiki page). But, also check them with the formulas there. Calculation is always prone to errors.